# Error when opening a jquery dialog on a textfield focus event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic textfield and i am binding it to focus event to open a dialog.

```
$('#formtable').on('focus', '#textbox1', function (e) {                        
 callOpenDialog('Dialog');             
});
```

where formtable is div container for the textfield and the function is defined as

```
function callOpenDialog(title)
{
 $("#Dialog").dialog({
        title: title,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 300,
        width: 300,           
        position: 'top'                      
    });
}
```

The problem is that:
1) On textfield focus, the dialog opens but the focus remains to the textfield itself.i want the focus to the dialog;
2)On closing the dialog an error is shown as
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method '_focusTabbable' of null

however when i bind to click event it works properly but i have to do it on focus event.

I tried using

```
e.preventDefault() 
or 
$("#Dialog").focus()
```

but to no avail.
Please help.

Comment: Is this Jquery UI dialog window?

Comment: yes its a jquery dialog

Answer (score 1):

I have got answer to the problems

1)i disabled the text box on focus event.

```
$('#formtable').on('focus', '#textbox1', function (e) {                        
   $("#textbox1").attr('disabled','disabled');
   callOpenDialog('Dialog');       
});
```

the focus is now transferring to the dialog box.

2)For this error "Cannot call method '_focusTabbable' of null"

I called destroy method on close event of jquery dialog.

```
  close: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).dialog('destroy');             
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  initialize your stuff in open callback method,

```
$( "#Dialog" ).dialog({
  open: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Bind an event listener to the dialogopen event:

```
$( "#Dialog" ).on( "dialogopen", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

To know more about Events & methods : http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/